# Use mongodb $in operator to search using array of arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, operators

```
var foo = [ [ 14, 31, 55, 56, 60, 19 ], [30, 32, 33, 50, 64, 6 ], [9, 15, 22, 35, 48, 3] ];

var bar = await Model.find({
    numbers: { $in: foo }
  });

console.log(bar);
```

When I try to run the above code above I get the error below.  The model is a mongoose model and the query runs with no problems in a raw mongodb query using robomongo.

```
{ [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "14,31,55,56,60,19" at path "numbers"]
  message: 'Cast to number failed for value "14,31,55,56,60,19" at path "numbers"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'number',
  value: [ 14, 31, 55, 56, 60, 19 ],
  path: 'numbers',
  reason: undefined }
```

Comment: Can you show how you have set up the `model`? Is the field `numbers` defined to be an array of the type `Number`? If so, it would fail.

Comment: The `CastError` is simply because your schema is defined as `Number` when you are in fact trying to compare "Arrays" being an array of numbers inside the `$in`. If you are saying this works without a schema involved the n perhaps your schema is incorrect for the data stored, since the `"numbers"` values themselves would be "arrays" rather than a single value defined in the schema. Your schema type should therefore be `"numbers": [Number]` and not `"numbers": Number` as you likely have them defined.

Comment: Note also that **exact matching** is probably not what you "really" want, and instead should be probably using a series of [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operations inside an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) expression. In that way the "sequence" of the numbers in the arrays does not need to be an "exact match" for the array as presented, but instead only needs to contain "all" the values in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `foo`, which is an array of arrays to Mongoose with a property which is expecting a `Number` value, thus Mongoose is complaining to you when it does it's validation by saying that an array is not a number.